# How to change Azure Monitoring action group admin address

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Azure budget alert that is using action group contains following text in the notification email:

> Contact {email address here} if you no longer want to be notified of this budget. If you need additional help, contact {support|link here}.

How that contact address can be changed?

I checked cost and billing management, Azure monitoring, and subscription level and could not find any setting for that.

Should I recreate the billing alert or action group or is there an API that gives access to change the admin email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contact email cannot be changed. The only way to change it is to re-create the budget (alert).

ref: Azure support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the recipient email address for budget alerts from the **Subscriptions** blade:

```
Subscriptions > {your-subscription} > Budgets > {your-budget} > Edit budget > Switch to 2. Set alerts > Update Alert recipients (email) > Save
```

[image: Azure Portal]

[image: Edit Budget]

Comment: Recipient(s) is different than `Contact {email address here} if you no longer` information printed in the actual email.

Comment: Also, that solution misses the fact about using Azure monitoring action group instead of a direct email from the budget alert itself.